# Array and List won't be both serialized in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

I try to use `XmlSerializer` in C# to serialize method calls by redirect calls to a transparent proxy that does serialization. I already added all types of method parameters as the extraTypes to the serializer. Everything works except for a particular case.

We have `List<TypeA>` and `TypeA[]` in method parameters, so they are supposed to be added into serializer. If I don't manually XmlInclude `List<TypeA>`, it throws this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TypeA, , Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] may not be used in this context.
```

Then I add `XmlInclude(typeof(List<TypeA>))` and thought it would solve the problem. However, a weird thing happened. It throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type TypeA[] may not be used in this context
```

I wrote test cases and I'm sure that `TypeA[]` worked if I don't add `List<TypeA>`.

Anyone know what caused this issue? Thanks!

Comment: can you confirm that `TypeA` can correctly serialize?

Comment: Any solution ? I'm facing the same situation.