# DataContract serializer doesn't work for similar types

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have an application where I need to use the data contract serializer for different, but similar types:

- Generic Lists
- Generic Collections
- Arrays

On request from Scrobi, here's a full model example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Model
{
    public Model()
    {
        List = new List<int>(new[] {1, 2, 3});
        Collection = new Collection<int>(new[] {4, 5, 6});
        Array = new[] {7, 8, 9};
    }

    [DataMember]
    public object List { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Collection { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Array { get; set; }

    public string SerializeMe()
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Model), GetKnownTypes());

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, this); // exception

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());
        }
    }

    public static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            typeof(List<int>),
            typeof(Collection<int>), // error
            typeof(int[]) // error
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is: I can't add the generic List, Collection and the array at the same time, because all of them use the same data contract.

When I only use one of the collection types, I am unable to serialize the other ones, because they are unknown (the data contract is present, but for the other type). And yes, the fields must be objects to make this work for my case (and in the real application, I cannot add attributes to them).

It is very impractical in the application I write to only use one of the types, as it is a kind of development environment and the developer can choose the type freely.

Is there any workaround against this limitation of the data contract serializer?

Thanks,

Comment: According to this [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts). "All list collections of the same type are considered to have the same data contract" So List<int> and Collection<int> are equivalent.

Comment: Sure. But you still can't serialize a list when you added a collection to the Known Types.

Comment: Maybe your example has been simplified but why would you be adding `Collection<int>` to the known types? If all collection are already equivalent & interchange able?

Comment: Because when you're adding a Collection<int> and try to serialize a List<int> it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you add your models where you are using different collections.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I added a full example.

Comment: Here's an equivalent issue with `XmlSerializer`: [XmlInclude : List and array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36308317/3744182).  Probably a similar solution would work here also.

Comment: You wrote, *and in the real application, I cannot add attributes to them*.  Does that mean you can't change the types being serialized at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial answer but for some reason when testing the `Collection<int>` throws an error when deserialising. Maybe you can work with this to find a full solution.

I created a `DataContractResolver` allowing you to override the `xsi:type` 
There is some documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-a-data-contract-resolver)

```
public class MyResolver : DataContractResolver
{
    public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        string name = string.Empty;
        bool isFound = false;
        if (type.Name == "Int32[]")
        {
            name = "IntArray";
            isFound = true;
        }
        if (type.Name.Contains("List") && type.FullName.Contains("Int")) //find List<int>
        {
            name = "IntList";
            isFound = true;
        }
        if (type.Name.Contains("Collection") && type.FullName.Contains("Int")) //find Collection<int> 
        {
            name = "IntCollection";
            isFound = true;
        }

        if (isFound)
        {
            XmlDictionary dictionary = new XmlDictionary();
            typeName = dictionary.Add(name);
            typeNamespace = dictionary.Add("http://tempuri.com");
            return true;
        }

        return knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, knownTypeResolver, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
    }

    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        if (typeName == "IntArray" )
        {
            return typeof(int[]);
        }
        if (typeName == "IntList")
        {
            return typeof(List<int>);
        }
        if (typeName == "IntCollection")
        {
            return typeof(Collection<int>);
        }


        return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null);
    }
}
```

You then don't need your `GetKnownTypes()` and create the `DataContractSerializer` like this:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Model),null, int.MaxValue, false, false,null, new MyResolver());
```

Hope this somewhat helps.

Comment: Great! This looks like what I was looking for and certainly gives me enough pointers in the right direction. Thank you very much :-)